# Let $X=\{0,1\}$ and $\tau =\{ \emptyset , X, \{0\} \}$. Is $(x_n)=0,0,... $ convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

> Let $X=\{0,1\}$ and $\tau =\{ \emptyset , X, \{0\} \}$. And $(x_n)=0,0,... $.
>
> Is $(x_n)$ convergence ?

$(X,\tau)$ is not a Hausdorff.

$(x_n)$ converges to $0$ since:

the neighborhoods of $0$ are $\{0\}$ and $X$, all of them contain all terms of the sequence.

$(x_n)$ converges to $1$ since:

the only neighborhood of $1$ is $X$, which is contain all terms of the sequence.

So $(x_n)$ convergence for all $x\in X$. Is that true, please?

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did it right. What you probably meant at the end is that for all $x\in X$, $x$ is a limit of the sequence $(x_n)$, which is what you just proved.

That's an example that uniqueness of the limit fails for general non-Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: To be pedantic, there are non-Hausdorff spaces in which limits of sequences are unique. Spaces satisfying this property are known as $T_{1\frac{1}{2}}$ spaces. I would like to attach here some documentation about them but, unfortunately, there isn't a lot.

Comment: Of course, I meant "in general". @Dog_69

Comment: Yes, you did. My apologizes, sir.